# SQL Server: Check constraint

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I am trying to create a check constraint in SQL Server.

I have a table called `Studies` which has '`pnr`', '`courseCode`', '`assignment`'.
I have a table called `Student` which has '`pnr`'.
I have a table called `Course` which has '`courseCode`'.
I have a table called `Assignment` which has '`courseCode`', '`assignment`', '`assignmentPoints`'.

Now I want to check that prevents the admin from inserting a `pnr` into `Studies` if that `pnr` is currently already attending courses worth to much points, the limit is 45 points.

I have gotten this far but it doesn't work.

```
create function EnrollmentFunction (@pnr varchar(10)) returns varchar(10)
as
begin
    if exists (
             select sum(assignmentPoints) as Points 
             from   Assignment a 
               join Studies s
                 on a.courseCode = s.courseCode 
                    and a.assignmentName = s.assignmentName 
                    and a.sectionName = s.sectionName 
                    and pnr = @pnr
             where assignmentPoints > 45)
        return 'False'
    return 'True'
end
```

---

```
alter table Studies
with check add constraint CK_Points
check (dbo.EnrollmentFunction(pnr) = 'True')
```

---

However when I run insert on that specific student and add a course when that student already is above the limit for points it goes through, the check is not preventing the insert.

Please help!

Comment: do you need total assignment points for a pnr to be > 45 or any one assignment point  for a course and an assignment > 45?

Comment: Your function ignores its parameter. That's probably the first thing to fix.

Comment: The sum of the points the student is already taking must not be 45 points or more.

Comment: is it a mistake that there is a pnr value hard-coded into that function.

Comment: I just used that value for testing, it could as well be @pnr, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Dont know the logic of your function but syntax should look something like this.....

```
create function EnrollmentFunction 
(@pnr varchar(10)) 
returns varchar(10)
as
begin
  DECLARE @RtnValue varchar(10);

    if exists ( select 1 
                from Assignment a 
                join Studies s   on a.courseCode = s.courseCode 
                                and a.assignmentName = s.assignmentName 
                                and a.sectionName = s.sectionName 
                                and pnr = @pnr
                where assignmentPoints > 45
               )
       BEGIN
          SET @RtnValue = 'False'
       END
    ELSE 
       BEGIN
         SET @RtnValue = 'True'
       END

   RETURN @RtnValue;    
end
```

Comment: If OP wants total assignment points > 45, you can use `having sum(assignmentPoints) > 45` instead of  `where assignmentPoints > 45`

Comment: This does not take into account the sum of the points the student is already taking. I tried using your syntax with the sum query I had used, it did not work however =(

Answer (score 0):

```
create function EnrollmentFunction 
(@pnr varchar(10)) 
returns varchar(10)
as
begin
  DECLARE @RtnValue varchar(10);

    if exists ( select sum(assignmentPoints) as Points from Assignment a join Studies s 
on a.courseCode = s.courseCode and a.assignmentName = s.assignmentName and a.sectionName = s.sectionName and pnr = @pnr
where assignmentPoints > 45
               )
       BEGIN
          SET @RtnValue = 'True'
       END
    ELSE 
       BEGIN
         SET @RtnValue = 'False'
       END

   RETURN @RtnValue;    
end
```

This does not work.. It will return 'False' if the student is taking courses worth 45 points and it will return 'False' if he does not. So either the result is something less than 45, say for example 35. Or it will say null. Either way the result is 'False'.